# Extract numbers from String Array

Tags: regex, scala, scala-collections

I have a Array of Strings

```
scala> tokens
res34: Array[String] = Array(The, value, of, your, profile, is, 234.2., You, have, potential, to, gain, 8.3, more.)
```

Here each of comma separated value is a String.
I want to extract numbers from this i.e. my output should be *result = (234.2, 8.3)* & it should be mutable so that I can read from another array and append values

What data structure should I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider

```
import scala.util._
tokens.flatMap(s => Try( s.split("\\W+").mkString(".").toDouble ).toOption)
```

where we tokenize further each array string into *words*  and append them by a dot (this ought to strip out for instance trailing dots); we convert the resulting tokens into doubles whenever possible (note `Try` `toOption` will deliver `None` for failed conversions). With `flatMap` we keep only successful conversion.

Comment: I'm new at Scala. What is _xs_ here? & are we splitting individual tokens from array or entire sentence?

Comment: Used now `tokens` instead of `xs` :) We split each token in the array in an attempt to extract "words" only (alphanumeric sequences) which are glued up with dots (mkString(".")) and then we try to convert them onto doubles.

Comment: Just a query - What if one of the numbers has comma. for example,  `232,332.33`

Comment: Good point, for this case the comma may be removed, e.g. `s.replaceAll(",","").split("\\W+").mkString(".").toDouble`

Answer (score 3):

Simply filter your array with regex

```
val numericRegex: String = "\\d+\\.\\d+"
tokens filter(_.matches(numericRegex))
```

Note that the 6'th value ***232.2.*** is not a number. you must remove the last dot "." so it will be ***232.2***

If values include spaces than you have to trim them

```
tokens map (_.trim) filter (_.matches(numericRegex))
res28: Array[String] = Array(234.2, 8.3)
```

Answer (score 1):

With Regex, you can use this code to catch all the numbers:

```
\d+\.?\d+
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/pZomjn/1

Answer (score 1):

In Scala there is a syntactic sugar to compose `map` and `filter` called [**for comprehension**](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html). Below is a version of regex approach based on `for`:

```
val regex = ".*\\d+\\.?\\d+.*"
val nums = for {
    str <- tokens if str.matches(regex)
    numStr = str.trim.split("\\W+").mkString(".")
} yield numStr.toDouble
```

It gives the desired output:

```
nums: Array[Double] = Array(234.2, 8.3)
```