# Extract number from string. Regular expression vs Try construct?

Tags: regex, performance, scala, exception

This question was inspired by [Extract numbers from String Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459723/extract-numbers-from-string-array) question.

Consider we have a `List` of arbitrary alphabetic and numeric strings:

```
val ls = List("The", "first", "one", "is", "11", "the", "second", "is" "22")
```

The goal is to form a list of numbers extracted from the original list: `val nums: List[Int] = List(11, 22)`

There are two different approaches possible (AFAIK):

1. Using `Try` construct:

   ```
   val nums = ls.flatMap(s => Try(s.toInt).toOption)
   ```

   This solution looks concise but it will have a huge overhead to handle exceptions.
2. Using `matches` method:

   ```
   val nums = ls.filter(_.matches("\\d+")).map(_.toInt)
   ```

   Here the most time-consuming part is regexp matching.

Which one is better by performance?

From my point of view usage of exception mechanism in such simple operation is a like "using a sledge-hammer to crack a nut".

Comment: Don't use exceptions with normal control flow. It's misleading, bad for performance and doesn't scale. Use exceptions for the *exceptional* cases.

Comment: I'm not saying you should go the regex way, but you could optimize your version by a) (re-)using a precompiled regex, such as `val Reg = "(\\d+)".r` and b) doing the `filter` and the `map` in one single step instead of two, e.g. `ls.collect{ case Reg(n) => n.toInt }`

Comment: If it's really about performance (and not about style or idioms): in your example, only 2 out of 9 elements are valid numbers. Is that a typical composition of your input list? Discussing performance doesn't make sense without knowing that aspect. If your list contains little to no strings which aren't numbers, then the exception variant will surely be faster (since there's nothing to catch), whereas the regex variant will perform the better the more invalid numbers are part of the list. There is no universal answer to your question.

Comment: @fxlae I'm learning scala and this question arose when I saw that the most popular answer for the question mentioned at the beginning of my post uses `Try` which is not good I think. The universal answer to my question IMHO should consider three different situations: if F is the possibility to meet number in the list than the first situation is F is almost 0, the second F = 0,5, and finally  F is almost 1. BTW: I'm quite new to stack overflow, should I update my question with these details or comment is enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend you test this stuff out yourself, you can learn a lot!  Commence Scala REPL:

```
scala> import scala.util.Try
import scala.util.Try

< import printTime function from our repo >

scala> val list = List("The", "first", "one", "is", "11", "the", "second", "is", "22")
list: List[String] = List(The, first, one, is, 11, the, second, is, 22)

scala> var x: List[Int] = Nil
x: List[Int] = List()
```

OK, the environment is set up. Here's your first function (Try):

```
scala> def f1(l: List[String], n: Int) = { 
  var i = 0
  while (i < n) { 
    x = l.flatMap(s => Try(s.toInt).toOption)
    i += 1 
  }
}
f1: (l: List[String], n: Int)Unit
```

The second function (regex):

```
scala> def f2(l: List[String], n: Int) = { 
  var i = 0
  while (i < n) { 
    x = l.filter(_.matches("\\d+")).map(_.toInt)
    i += 1 
  }
}
f2: (l: List[String], n: Int)Unit
```

Timings:

```
scala> printTime(f1(list, 100000)) // Try
time: 4.152s

scala> printTime(f2(list, 100000)) // regex
time: 565.107ms
```

Well, we've learned that handling exceptions inside a flatMap is a very inefficient way to do things. This is partly because exception handling produces bad assembly code, and partly because flatMaps with options do a lot of extra allocation and boxing. Regex is ~8x faster! But...is regex fast?

```
scala> def f3(l: List[String], n: Int) = { 
  var i = 0
  while (i < n) { 
    x = l.filter(_.forall(_.isDigit)).map(_.toInt)
    i += 1 
  }
}
f3: (l: List[String], n: Int)Unit

scala> printTime(f3(list, 100000)) // isDigit
time: time: 70.960ms
```

Replacing regex with character `isDigit` calls gave us another order of magnitude improvement. The lesson here is to avoid try/catch handling at all costs, avoid using regex whenever possible, and don't be afraid to write performance comparisons!

Comment: Take a list that only contains strings representing valid numbers and the exception variant will be much faster. Yes, you used the list that was posted by the OP, but I'm not sure the OP is aware of this problem in the first place. What I'm trying to say: benchmarking is a difficult topic, especially if we can't make reasonable assumptions about the input.

Comment: You're right that if exceptions are never thrown, then the `Try` version is almost as fast as the `isDigit` version: testing on 1m iterations on a list with 8 numeric strings, the times are 1.428s (Try), 4.631s (regex), and 0.938s (isDigit).  

Add one non-numeric element, and the times are: 7.148s (Try), 5.962s (regex), and 0.992s (isDigit).

If you're throwing exceptions with any reasonable frequency (here was ~10% of elements), then Try is definitely the slowest model.