# Extract Number from string into a list in Scala

Tags: string, scala

I have the following string :

```
var myStr = "abc12ef4567gh90ijkl789"
```

The size of the list is not fixed and it contains number in between. I want to extract the numbers and store them in the form of a list in this manner:

```
List(12,4567,90,789)
```

I tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459723/extract-numbers-from-string-array) but cannot extend it to my case. I just want to know if there is any faster or efficient solution instead of just traversing the string and extracting the numbers one by one using brute force ? Also, the string can be arbitrary length.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems you may just collect the numbers using

```
("""\d+""".r findAllIn myStr).toList
```

See the [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/KLR2d4). `\d+` matches one or more digits, [`findAllIn`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/matching/Regex.html#findAllIn(source:CharSequence):scala.util.matching.Regex.MatchIterator) searches for multiple occurrences of the pattern inside a string (and also un-anchors the pattern so that partial matches could be found).

If you prefer a splitting approach, you might use

```
myStr.split("\\D+").filter(_.nonEmpty).toList
```

See [another demo](https://ideone.com/AGdSez).  Here, `\D+` matches one or more non-digit chars, and these chunks are used to split on (texts between these chunks land in the result). `.filter(_.nonEmpty)` will remove empty items that usually appear due to matches at the start/end of the string.